# Simulate in Puma-EM given radiation pattern

Tags: antenna, simulation, radiation

Is it possible to simulate the EM field in [Puma-EM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/puma-em/) if the radiation pattern is supplied instead of a 3D model of the antenna?

Is there other (free) simulation software that can do this? I need to generate a RadHaz zone ("Radiation Hazard", an isosurface of constant intensity) from a microwave anetenna.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Puma-EM is designed to iterate of the Rao-Wilton-Glisson functions of a 3D model of an EM source (in essence iterating over the edges of this 3D model). It is better to find an FMM solver that takes in sets of points, and overload those points to include the radiation pattern.

Regardless, for far-field calculations, you can directly get the intensity field by multiply the radiation pattern (linear and unnormalised) by the power and dividing by radius squared ([see here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305371/calculate-em-field-or-intensity-field-given-radiation-pattern)). For near-field calculations, you need the design of the antenna anyway.